# Postgres Many-To-Many table: what does @JoinTable, "owning side of relationship" and "ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE" mean?

Tags: typescript, postgresql, typeorm

I'm new to database so sorry if this is basic. I'm using postgres and typescipt typeorm to create two tables: `user` and `organization` and they have many-to-many relationship:

In the definition of the `user` Entity:

```
  @ManyToMany(
    () => Organization,
    organization => organization.users,
  )
  @JoinTable()
  organization: Organization[];
```

And in the definition of the `organization` Entity:

```
  @ManyToMany(
    () => User,
    user => user.organization
  ) 
  users: User[]
```

So I put `@JoinTable()` in the `user` Entity, meaning that `user` is the "Owning side" of the relationship.

After the tables are created, I see that a `user_organization_organization` table is automatically created as well:

```
my_app=# \d user_organization_organization;
       Table "public.user_organization_organization"
     Column     |  Type   | Collation | Nullable | Default
----------------+---------+-----------+----------+---------
 userId         | integer |           | not null |
 organizationId | integer |           | not null |
Indexes:
    "PK_c38fd18fe27910de6ed9288f3a1" PRIMARY KEY, btree ("userId", "organizationId")
    "IDX_962e308ac31da9ba567b2003b7" btree ("userId")
    "IDX_b0904d939c07407eef53706c47" btree ("organizationId")
Foreign-key constraints:
    "FK_962e308ac31da9ba567b2003b7b" FOREIGN KEY ("userId") REFERENCES "user"(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
    "FK_b0904d939c07407eef53706c475" FOREIGN KEY ("organizationId") REFERENCES organization(id)
```

Can anyone help me understand some concepts:

1. What exactly is the "owning" side of a relationship?
2. How do we decide which is the owning side? / where to put `@JoinTable()` ?

I noticed that if I had put the `@JoinTable()` in `organization` Entity definition, then the automatically created table will have name `organization_users_user`, instead of `user_organization_organization`; Moreover, `ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE` will be on the `FOREIGN KEY ("organizationId")` instead of `FOREIGN KEY ("userId")`.

3. What does this default name pattern `A_B_B` mean?
4. What does  `ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE` mean?

Comment: To decide what is the Owning side of the relationship would be defined by the architecture of the database.  A student in a college takes many courses and courses have many students.  If the student is the base relationship in the database, everything is built around the student, the student owns the relationship and vice versa.

Comment: As for Cascading that is the relationship among the record.  If you delete a student, to extend on the previous comment, you'll want to also delete any record of the student in the relational tables.  A student takes Math 101, you delete the student and with cascading enabled it will automatically delete the record in the course table as well.  Cascading is similar to a cleanup process. Anything done to the main record also effects the relationships.  It is very powerful, and at the same time can be very dangerous if not implemented properly.